# What is difference between the Advantage Database Server free table and Advantage Database Server Normal table

Tags: advantage-database-server

What is difference between the Advantage Database Server **free table** and Advantage Database Server normal table.

Thanks !

Comment: This is covered in detail in the documentation. See *Advantage Developer's Guide->Part I Advantage and the Advantage Data Architect->Chapter 2 - Creating Tables->Free Tables Versus Database Tables*.

Comment: The documentation is available online here: http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage12/devguide_free_tables_versus_database_tables.htm

Comment: unfortunately the `advantagedatabase.com` links no longer work. also, a search on SAP's sites turns up almost nothing for AdvantageDB - there is content there, but it's not exposed to the search engine on the site(s).

Comment: ... as of today there is still some information available [here](https://help.sap.com/docs/SUPPORT_CONTENT/eim/3361406403.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Free table - The table is independent of a data dictionary, it's just a set of files in the fs (table.adt, table.adi, table.adm).
- Dictionary table - The table con only be used after logging into the specific data dictionary that owns the table.

The technical difference is that some bytes in the adt file header are different, so that you can't open a dictionary table with a free connection.